# How to use a Ruby-style map on a Java vector?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a feeling this is a question that Google could quickly answer if I knew the Java terminology for what I want to do, but I don't, so in Stack Overflow I trust. :)

I have a vector of `Object`s, and I want an array of `String`s containing the string representation of each element in the vector, as generated by calling `toString()` on each element.

In Ruby (or Perl, or Python, or Scheme, or any of the millions of other languages with a `map` method), here's how I'd do it:

```
vector.map(&:to_s) do |string|
  # do stuff
end
```

How can I do the equivalent in Java? I'd like to write something like this:

```
Vector<Object> vector = ...;
String[] strings = vector.map(somethingThatMagicallyCallsToString);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As an orthogonal point, this *might* be useful info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-java-vector-class-is-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated. Your best bet is to use an `ArrayList` (if possible).

Comment: It may also depend on the result you want to have. Do you need it to be `String[]` or would an iterator be sufficient?

Comment: @Howard: An iterator should be fine.

Comment: @Jits: Thanks for the info on `ArrayList`; I wasn't aware of `Vector`'s unfortunate synchronisation behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're OK bringing in [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you can use its `transform` function.

```
Iterable<String> strings = Iterables.transform(vector, Functions.toStringFunction());
```

`transform`'s second argument is an instance of the `Function` interface. Usually you'll write your own implementations of this, but Guava provides `toStringFunction()` and a few others.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was after. Strange that they called it `transform`. ;)

Comment: @Josh "Map" is overloaded, what with `java.util.Map` meaning something quite different. I think `transform` better describes it anyway, but it's not the most common name for it.

Comment: Yes, that's an unfortunate namespace collision. Lisps were calling the list transformation "map" long before Java was born, so I blame Bill Joy personally for this confusion. ;)

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be:

```
Vector<Object> vector = ...;
ArrayList strings = new ArrayList();
for (Object obj : vector) {
  strings.add(obj.toString());
}
return strings.toArray(new String[1]);
```

Comment: I certainly **could** do it this way, but it is quite clunky compared to a map. :)

Comment: clunky but safe, I like it